# Tracing Linux commands using Python

Tags: python, linux, trace

I have a Python script which uses `os.system()` to call certain commands an Linux machine.

These commands might be standard commands such as `ls`, `grep` etc., or some custom commands present on that machine.

I want to trace what syscalls get called by these commands, but within the Python script itself. So, once I do:

```
os.system(command)
```

I want to return a list of all system calls made by that particular command.

So that I can iterate over the list and filter for any syscalls I need to investigate. Ideally, what I am planning to do is create a dictionary which will help me map the parameters that I gave to my command above, and what went in to the syscall eventually.

Is there a nice Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: do you have the ability to change this code from calling `os.system(...)` to, say, `self.system(...)`? If so, write a wrapper that logs each call before making the actual call.

Comment: I was about to suggest `os.system('strace ' + command)` and parse the output but from @ColinSchoen's answer it looks like p-trace is a better way.

Comment: yes. Got this. but how do i use the ptrace library in my python module and not just from command line ? Can you please give an example ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at python p-trace

http://python-ptrace.readthedocs.org/en/latest/syscall.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.